# uninitialized constant for module included in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've read a bunch of other SO posts on this and it seems the convention is to place the module in lib (lib/my_module.rb) and name it CamelCase (module MyModule) and then include it in the model (include MyModule). I did all this and still get "uninitialized constant Model::MyModule". I was wondering if something changed in Rails 4 or if I have to do something in my config/environment.rb file. Here is my code:

app/models/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    include KarmaExtension # error at this line

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Comment"

    ...
end
```

lib/karma_extension.rb

```
module KarmaExtension
    def karma_recieved_from?(sender)
        sender ? !karmas.where("sender_id = ?", sender.id).empty? : true
    end
end
```

and my config/environment.rb just in case (have not touched this file)

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
RailsHnClone::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: Convention being followed seems correct. Rails look for `my_module.rb` whenever it encounters `MyModule`. Try to `require` the file on the top of your model once; to crosscheck whether file is being actually included or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/lib` to your `load_path`:

```
# in config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

And require your lib:

```
# in config/initializers/karma_extension.rb
require 'karma_extension'
```

Found the answer here: http://blog.chrisblunt.com/rails-3-how-to-autoload-and-autorequire-your-custom-library-code/

Comment: Don't forget to restart your server before this will work.  Thanks for the answer!